# Update hostname with udhcpc

Tags: dhcp, udhcpc

I have a small Debian-based Linux device which set's its hostname by calling `udhcpc`:

```
udhcpc -i $interface -S -x hostname:mydevice
```

(Of course `$interface` is defined earlier in the script calls `udhcpc`.)

This works as intended, on my router I can see *mydevice* as **active host name** for this device.

My device - after obtaining the lease - mounts its new root file system from NFS and then `chroot`s into it.

`udhcpc` will be sending renew requests to my router:

```
# cat /var/log/messages | grep dhcp
Jan  1 04:00:07 udhcpc: started, v1.28.1
Jan  1 04:00:07 udhcpc: sending discover
Jan  1 04:00:09 udhcpc: performing DHCP renew
Jan  1 04:00:09 udhcpc: sending discover
Jan  1 04:00:09 udhcpc: sending select for a.b.c.d
Jan  1 04:00:09 udhcpc: lease of a.b.c.d obtained, lease time 600
***NOW THE CHROOT HAPPENS***
Jan  1 04:05:09 udhcpc: sending renew to r.o.u.t
Jan  1 04:05:09 udhcpc: lease of a.b.c.d obtained, lease time 600
Jan  1 04:10:09 udhcpc: sending renew to r.o.u.t
Jan  1 04:10:09 udhcpc: lease of a.b.c.d obtained, lease time 600
```

I want to update the hostname after the `chroot` happens.

**What have I tried:**

- killing `udhcpc` and restarting it with the new desired hostname: FAIL (NFS drops, system stalls)
- checking `udhcpc`'s manual: FAIL (haven't found any mention of updating hostname on a running instance)

Any idea is appreciated: all I want is to update the hostname on the active `udhcpc`.

Important: it's enough (accepted as answer) if I can update the hostname on a *"sending renew to r.o.u.t"* event.

Answer (score 2):

From `udhcpc --help`:

> -F NAME     Ask server to update DNS mapping for NAME

For example: `udhcpc -F $(hostname)`

Comment: It didn't worked for me. Once udhcpc successfully set the hostname after `bind`, it's not able to *update* it. I had to modify udhcpc's source to reach that functionality. They might have been fixed it since then though.